# Good books on Ruby based DSL

Tags: ruby, dsl

I'm trying to create a DSL in ruby, can you suggest me some good books? I looked around amazon and safari but so far couldn't find any.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some possible sources:

- [Metaprogramming Ruby: Program Like
  the Ruby Pros (Prag Progs, Feb
  2010)](http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby)
- [Martin Fowler's DSL
  Book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780132107549) (in beta)

Answer (score 6):

- Martin Fowler's **Domain Specific
  Languages** book contains some Ruby
  examples in the Internal DSLs
  section. You can read the [work in
  progress](http://martinfowler.com/dslwip) on his web site or if
  you've got a Safari account then it's
  available as a [rough cut](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780132107549).
- There are also some slides [here](http://obiefernandez.com/presentations/obie_fernandez-agile_dsl_development_in_ruby.pdf)
  from an **Agile DSL Development in
  Ruby** presentation by [Obie
  Fernandez](http://obiefernandez.com/)
- **Metaprogramming Ruby: Domain-Specific Languages for Programmers** (PDF [here](http://www.vanderburg.org/Speaking/Stuff/oscon05.pdf)) from an   OSCON '05 session by Glenn Vanderburg
- There is a relevant chapter **One Lair and Twenty Ruby DSLs** in the [ThoughtWorks Anthology](http://pragprog.com/titles/twa/thoughtworks-anthology) which is [available in PDF as an example chapter](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/twa/martin_fowler.pdf).